# Как в cmd Windows 10 добавить окно, которое бы требовало закрытие командной строки

Tags: windows, cmd

Также скажем как при выходе из Paint без сохранения, чтобы выводилось окно, на котором был вопрос "Вы уверены что хотите закрыть командную строку?". Или убрать возможность закрытия через крестик в правом верхнем углу, а закрытие только через команду?

Comment: Никак, для этого вам нужно написать свою программу которая позволит вам выполнить заданные условия.

Comment: Используя командный интерпретатор Вы НЕ сможете напрямую обратиться к WinAPI для вызова нужных функций. Как правильно отметил RifmaMan, нужно внешнее решение - утилиты. Или инструмент способный обратиться к API: VBscript, Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно решения давно существуют. Стоит лишь "загуглить" "disable close button".
Я предпочел бы решение, исходя из имеющегося системного инструментария, - это [Powershell](https://www.makak.ch/disable-close-button-in-powershell-window/).

Вот пример кода для запрета кнопки "**закрыть**" редактора MSpaint.

```
#Calling user32.dll methods for Windows and Menus
$MethodsCall = '
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern long GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool EnableMenuItem(long hMenuItem, long wIDEnableItem, long wEnable);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern long SetWindowLongPtr(long hWnd, long nIndex, long dwNewLong);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool EnableWindow(long hWnd, int bEnable);
'
 
#Create a new namespace for the Methods to be able to call them
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodsCall -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
 
$MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002L #Indicates that the menu item is disabled, but not grayed, so it cannot be selected.
#... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647636(v=vs.85).aspx
 
$SC_CLOSE = 0xF060
#... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx
 
 
#Get window handle of Paint process (Ensure there is only one Paint window opened)
$PSWindow = (Get-Process mspaint) | where {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "*Paint*"}
$hwnd = $PSWindow.MainWindowHandle
 
#Get System menu of windows handled
$hMenu = [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetSystemMenu($hwnd, 0)


#Disable X Button and window itself
[Win32.NativeMethods]::EnableMenuItem($hMenu, $SC_CLOSE, $MF_DISABLED) | Out-Null
```